# Why is gettext giving me automatically incorrect translations?

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

I am using gettext translations for my Django project and I keep adding to the .po file new and new translations by `makemessages` and `compilemessages`.
What is happening now is that when I make messages then I check the .po file and there many of the strings have been automatically translated, although this is 100% unique string.

example:
Now generated:

```
#: .\agregator\models.py:1855
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "Distribution order"
msgid "Distribution Product Parameters"
msgstr "Objednávka u distribuce"
```

it automatically translated according to the `msgid "Distribution order"` that is not any close to the actual string neither there is any link to this `msgid`.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening in the background and how can I remove all such links so for `msgstr` I get only empty strings, (unless the strings are 100% similar)? Thank you in advance.

My tip is that the `msgid` is allocated based on fragments of strings, looking for the "best match". If this was the case - how to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `msgmerge` finds translations for similar strings, it will suggest them as "fuzzy". This is what you see here.

Fuzzy translations are *not* meant to be used/deployed by your application. If you compile your `.po` file into an `.mo` file with `msgmerge` (this is what `compilemessages` probably does) these fuzzy translations are ignored.

Just leave the fuzzy translations in the `.po` file. They don't hurt and they make future translations easier because the translator does not have to translate from scratch but correct the auto-suggested translation instead.